# NesC programming language

Tags: nesc

Does anyone knows where I can find tutorials and code samples, basic and advanced, of NesC programming language.

Best regards

Comment: Mote programming .. fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you will find many examples and many other documentations.
http://docs.tinyos.net

Answer (score 3):

For me(Study TinyOS 2 years and use it do some embedded projects) I write some advise to you:

1. read the book [《the tinyos programming》](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521896061) and tutorials
2. check out the [tinyos contrib project](https://github.com/tyll/tinyos-2.x-contrib), read some interesting projects.
3. read the paper by Philip Levis 《Experiences from a Decade of TinyOS Development》， this is very important paper for tinyos. I translate it into chinese [---> look this translate](http://forestgump.me/2012/12/experiences-from-a-decade-of-tinyos-development/)

I think if you want to really know nesc programming, you must read the source code app.c(compiled by compiler ncc) and the .nc source file difference, Also, You'd better read TinyOS system's Timer and Task schedule and Virtualize part, This design, TinyOS use 5 more years to evolute.if you want to know more about the system design, Just read the [TEPS.](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/TEPs)
for example, In [TEP131](http://www.tinyos.net/tinyos-2.1.0/doc/html/tep131.html), reading this paper, You will know TinyOS 2.x platform creating steps. even you can create you own platform.

Have fun~